# Hibernate: query entity's field from two possible places?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Is it possible to fetch entity's field from 2 possible tables?

For example:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "TABLE_A")
   public class A{

     @Id
     @Column(name = "ID")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;
   }

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "TABLE_B")
   public class B{

     @Id
     @Column(name = "ID")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;
   }

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_PARENT")
public class PARENT{

  // This field needs to be fetched from A table or from B table!!! by some
  // conditions
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "A_B_ID")
  private A a;                     
}
```

a field in Parent class needs to be fetched from table_A or table_b
according to some condition!

Any idea will be appreciated!

Clarification: if the Parent actually points to B instance i wan't to fetch 
instance of B! Table per class inheritance only looks in A's table because we specified in the Parent class that the field his of A type!?

Do you have other ideas?

Comment: How would you set an object of class `B` into that property?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using hibernate inheritance functionality;
here is an example;
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-concrete-class-annotation-xml-mapping/

Comment: But if i use table per class i'll will always get in PARENT class an A  instance! Because when using table per class we need to specify the type of the object in order to look for him in his table! I need that if the id in PARENT that points to A object his actually of type B to look for him in B table?!

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be inherit `A` and `B` from a common class, for instance `C` and refer `C` in `Parent` class. A draft could be:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AB {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
...
}

@Entity
public class A extends AB {
...
}

@Entity
public class B extends AB {
...
}

@Entity
public class Parent {
    ...
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne
    private AB ab;
}
```

[documentation section 2.2.4.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/)